# What exaclty does the Security_Type column do?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in MySQL. When I run SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS LIKE 'sp_name' I get some columns that explains the stored procedure.

The definer is set to Definer root@% and Security_type is set to DEFINER. Does this mean that only the root-user can call the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Does this mean that only the root-user can call the stored procedure?*

No, it doesn't. Any user with EXECUTE privilege can call this procedure.

From the reference - *The SQL SECURITY characteristic can be used to specify whether the routine should be executed using the permissions of the user who creates the routine or the user who invokes it.*

[CREATE PROCEDURE Syntax.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html)